# Ionic2 : POST request not working

Tags: node.js, post, ionic2

I prepared my server with Node.js (tested with Chrome Postman and everything works fine). It is installed in an Ubuntu 16.04 Server virtual machine and Im testing everything from the host machine (win7). Then I added Ionic2 framework on my virtual machine and start the development of the front-end but I have problem in sending the request POST.

I created a provaider with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyProvider1 {

data: any;

constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.data = null;
}

login(id,pwd){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/',
                    JSON.stringify({
                        username: id ,
                        password: pwd
                    }), {headers: headers})
                .subscribe(res => {
                    console.log(res.json());
                });     
}
}
```

It should be working but when the login function is called, my node.js server logs a strange request:

> OPTION / 200 0.348 ms -13

Instead of a `POST` request. Moreover, in my host chrome browser the console shows the following failure:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Just for trial I removed the `{headers: headers}` and the `http.post` became:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/',
                        JSON.stringify({
                            username: id ,
                            password: pwd
                        }))
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        console.log(res.json());
                    });
```

In this way Morgan logs in my Node.js a `POST` request BUT the req.body is empty (if I do `console.log(req.body)` the output will be `{}` ).

Just in case, I post in the following part of my server Node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//------------------------------------
//Configuration
//------------------------------------
var config = require('./config.js');
var port = process.env.PORT || config.SERVICE_PORT;
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//------------------------------------
//Routes
//------------------------------------
app.use('/admin',   require('./app/routes/admin.js'));
app.use('/',        require('./app/routes/guest.js'));
app.use('/chat',    require('./app/routes/chat.js'));

//------------------------------------
//Server Start
//------------------------------------
mongoose.connect(config.database);
app.listen(port);
console.log('server start at port ' + port);
```

And my /app/routes/guest.js contains the following code:

```
...
router.route('/')
    .get(function(req,res){
        res.end('Welcome');
    })
    .post(function(req,res){
    UsersManager.login(req.body.username,req.body.password,function(err,user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                res.json({
                            success: false,
                            message: Const.notificationTokenAccessNOK
                        });
            }else{
                var token = TokenManager.createToken(user);
                res.json({
                            success: true,
                            message: Const.notificationTokenAccessOK,
                            token: token
                });
            }
        }); 
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not perform network request(atleast not directly) from your ionic2 code while testing it in chrome browser.

But if you want to, You can put proxy in `ionic.config.json` file as followed:

```
    {
        "proxies": [{
                "path": "/localhost/",
                "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8080/"
            }] 
}
```

then you can perform post request as followed :

```
this.http.post('/localhost/',
                        JSON.stringify({
                            username: id ,
                            password: pwd
                        }))
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        console.log(res.json());
                    });
```

Comment: Yes! It was a CORS issue and by setting a proxy as per your instruction it works. Thanks a lot